# Spring Boot Exception (Logged from /error controller)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting this exception. Can someone figure out what is the cause behind it?

```
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at com.shiksha.util.filters.PerformanceFilter.doFilter(PerformanceFilter.java:53)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at com.shiksha.util.filters.HttpRequestFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestFilter.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
 at 

  ...

 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My /error Controller

```
@RestController
public class IndexController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/*")
    public ResponseEntity<?> notFound(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Integer statusCode = null;
        Exception exception = null;
        try {
            statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
            exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception Case 1 from Index Controller");
        }


        ValidationErrorResponse validationResponse = new ValidationErrorResponse();
        validationResponse.setField("url");
        validationResponse.setMessage("Url Not Found.");
        HttpStatus finalStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        if(statusCode != null) {
            if(statusCode == 404) {
                validationResponse.setMessage("Url Not Found.");
            }else {
                validationResponse.setMessage("Some error occured");
            }
            finalStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
            if(exception != null) {
                try {
                    String exceptionMessage = StringUtils.isNotBlank(exception.getMessage())?exception.getMessage():"Exception : Logged from Index Controller";
                    LogException.logException(exceptionMessage, exception);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception Case 2 from Index Controller");
                }

            }
        }

        validationResponse.setField("url");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(validationResponse, finalStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

What happens is my Project also has @ExceptionHandler but after I start the service on prod, after some time exceptions stop going to @ExceptionHandler. Instead they are coming at ErrorController which should not happen since I have already catch the Exception. Exceptions are normally NullPointer which I already have caught in @ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Servlet filters always create a long horrible stacktrace. Have you looked at line 982 of Spring's FrameworkServlet to see what might be null? That's the beauty of open source :-)

Comment: Nothing much. This line is throwing exception.

Comment: Nothing much is great, in fact only one thing that might be null would be ideal as then you know what is null and you can move ahead and try to understand why. Do you have that line handy? Or if you can share the version you are using of the spring library that contains FrameworkServlet. It may be handy to see your controller code too.

Comment: can you post your `/error` resource?

Comment: This is the line 982
throw new NestedServletException("Request processing failed", ex);

I am using spring 
<spring.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>

Comment: Updated the question for /error controller